# SQL server - How to copy data in a column to other column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like

```
|name|
|a   |
....
```

`name` column has datatype is `ntext` I want to create a new column with other datatype `text` and it has same data with column `name`.

How to do that thanks

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `varchar(max)` instead of `text`.  The following adds the column and sets the value:

```
alter table t add newcol varchar(max);

update t
    set newcol = name;
```